# How to concat files creating codes for each of than?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the first thing I need to know is if exists a way to create two columns when I read a file and fill the column with the filename code(a filename ex: abcd275-2016-10-01, efg275-2016-10-01), the files always have 3 or 4 letters, a code and a day, I only want the letters and the day.

this is an example of the Dataframe i would like to built:

| Dados 1 | Dados 2 | Dados 3 | Dados 4 | Code | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4.00 | 4 | -3.95 | abcd | 2016-10-01 |
| 1 | 8.00 | 4 | -3.95 | abcd | 2016-10-02 |
| 2 | 2.00 | 4 | -3.95 | abcd | 2016-10-02 |
| 6 | 3.97 | 6 | -2.79 | efg | 2016-10-01 |
| 7 | 3.80 | 5 | -2.79 | efg | 2016-10-01 |
| 8 | 5.97 | 7 | -2.79 | efg | 2016-10-02 |

I tried this code but the first the DataFrame *dados* in the final of the loop don't got anything and I need it to get all the files DataFrames that *tmp_df* read

```
   dados = pd.DataFrame(columns=head_files)
   for i in diretorio_vtec:
      tmp_df = pd.read_table(i,
                           names=head_files)
      dados = pd.merge(dados, tmp_df)
```

Comment: Do the filenames always follow that pattern of four letters, 275, and then a YYYY-MM-DD date? Have you tried anything yet? Do you have code? Do you have errors?

Comment: Take a look at `os.walk()`. Or you can use `glob.glob()` with the `recursive=True` option.

Comment: @ddejohn I didn't try anything yet, I never worked with a directory big like this I don't even know about functions to read all, my thinking was trying some type of looping with the for, and about the patterns the format is: 
3 or 4 letters, 275, the day in this format YYYY-MM-DD date

Comment: @Barmar ok ill try to see how they work, thanks

Comment: You want to create two columns, but you only say one column filename. What is the other column?

Comment: @ddejohn ok thanks for all the attention and help, actually the Barmar helps a lot giving me functions to search the glob.glob() solve the problem of reading all the files now I only need to solve the problems of reading the file, create the DataFrame with the columns code and date from the file

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot for the command of glob.glob() help's a lot now the program I tried is already reading all the files, I only need to creat a dataframe with the files reading

Comment: Your question title indicates that your question is about reading all the files. If your actual question is about how to make a dataframe from a file, you need to provide an example of the file contents. And fix the title to describe your real problem.